# Referencing environment variable in KubernetesPodOperator `cmds`

Tags: kubernetes, airflow

I've built an image with an environment variable baked into it via `--build-args` and I want to reference that in the `cmds` of a `KubernetesPodOperator`.  My question is, what is the syntax for that?

This

```py
KubernetesPodOperator(
  ...
  cmds=cmds,
  ...
)
```

with `cmds = ["ls", "/app/$MY_ENV_VAR"]` or `["ls", "/app/${MY_ENV_VAR}"]` or `["ls", "/app/$(MY_ENV_VAR)"]` all return the same error, that, e.g., "`/app/$MY_ENV_VAR` does not exist."  It is not interpolating the environment variable correctly.  I can ensure that that environment variable `MY_ENV_VAR` exists in a container created from the image.

How am I meant to reference an environment variable in the `cmds` of a `KubernetesOperator`?

Comment: You can try setting the command like so: `['bash', '-c', 'ls /app/${MY_ENV_VAR}']` (or `sh` if `bash` is not in your image). Otherwise you could create a docker `ENTRYPOINT` referencing a shell script in which interpolation would likely work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding on Ludovic's comment:

You are running the command `ls`, which has no idea what an environment variable is. Environment variables are expanded by shells - `sh`,`bash`,`fish`etc.

So, in order to be able to expand environment variables, you need to put a shell around your command.

In containers this is usually done with a script which by custom is called `docker-entrypoint.sh`. We could argue whether this is good or bad practice, but usually it is put into the root directory `/`.

The other way is to start a shell in non-interactive mode via the `-c` flag.

### Preparation

```bash
export YOURORG=mwmahlberg
export IMAGENAME=stackoverflow-77971921
```

Of course, you might need to change this to your actual values. However, the [images mentioned here exist and can be run](https://hub.docker.com/r/mwmahlberg/stackoverflow-77971921/tags). To do so, simply use the exact exports as shown above.

You can find [all the files I used to build them in a Gist on GitHub](https://gist.github.com/mwmahlberg/83e6e1d17d9aaed6e005cf7bea73f4e9)

### docker-entrypoint.sh

Let's assume you have the following script:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# Exit immediately if a command exits with a non-zero status.
set -eo
env
```

and, the following `Dockerfile.entrypoint`:

```
FROM alpine:3
RUN apk add --no-cache bash
ADD --chmod=755 docker-entrypoint.sh /docker-entrypoint.sh
ENV MY_VAR="Hello World"

ENTRYPOINT ["/docker-entrypoint.sh"]
```

After running a docker build

```bash
$ docker build -t $YOURORG/$IMAGENAME:entrypoint -f Dockerfile.entrypoint
```

and an (optional) subsequent push

```bash
$ docker push $YOURORG/$IMAGENAME:entrypoint
```

you can run it (that image actually exists, you can simply run the command below):

```bash
$ docker run --rm $YOURORG/$IMAGENAME:entrypoint
```

### Non-intercative

The Dockerfile is simpler:

```
FROM mwmahlberg/stackoverflow-77971921:entrypoint
# The Environment variable MY_VAR is set in the parent image
ENTRYPOINT [ "/bin/bash","-c", "echo $MY_VAR"]
```

Build it

```bash
$ docker build -t $YOURORG/$IMAGENAME:non-interactive -f Dockerfile.non-interactive
```

(push it if you want) and run it:

```bash
$ docker run --rm $YOURORG/$IMAGENAME:non-interactive
Hello World
```

Changing the env var is simple enough:

```bash
$ docker run -e MY_VAR=foo --rm $YOURORG/$IMAGENAME:non-interactive
foo
```